# How to remove the default selected item for <f:selectItems>

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to implement a dropdown which depends on another dropdown. On change of 'Document Type' dropdown, the dropdown 'Document Category' should be updated.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="docType" value="#{docBean.docIndex}"
    <p:ajax listener="#{docBean.onDocTypeChange}" 
            update="docCategory" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Select Document Type --"    
                  itemValue="" 
                  noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{docBean.docTypeList}" 
                   var="n"  
                   itemLabel="#{n.name}" 
                   itemValue="#{n.id}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

 <p:selectOneMenu id="docCategory" 
                  value="#{docBean.catIndex}"
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Select Document Category --" 
                  itemValue="" 
                  noSelectionOption="true" />   
    <f:selectItems value="#{docBean.catList}" 
                   var="n"  
                   itemLabel="#{n.name}" 
                   itemValue="#{n.id}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

For ‘Document Type’ selectOneMenu, the HTML renders as:

```
<select id="myForm:docType_input" name=" myForm:docType_input ">
   <option value="" selected="selected">-- Select Document Category --</option>
   <option value="0" selected="selected">A</option>
   <option value="1">B</option>
   <option value="2">C</option>
   <option value="3">D</option>
   <option value="4">E</option>
</select>
```

And on the UI in the ‘Document Type’ dropdown, it is showing option ‘A’ as default selected option whereas it should be "-- Select Document Type –-".
How to fix this? However, the 'Document Category' dropdown is displaying correctly with the value "-- Select Document Category --" as the default selected option

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change type of docIndex to type that can set null or empty such as String, Integer and so on.

May be you use int(primitive type), and that field are declared but not initialized, the compiler will be set 0 by default.

Thus, docIndex equal to 0 that corresponding to `<option value="0" selected="selected">A</option>`

See also: [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: If I change the docIndex to Integer (Wrapper of int) would that fix the issue? I am loading the list values from a database. I am getting that into the docTypeList property of docBean. The docType table contains the id and names of all document Types.

Comment: Change it. If you did not set docIndex value at first time, the problem occurs because docIndex is equal to 0 by default

Comment: So  I need to initialize the docIndex value to ?

Comment: if you set docIndex=0 or did not set your selected will select A,
docIndex=1 your selected will select B,
docIndex=2 your selected will select C and etc.
Thus, If you want to selected -- Select Document Category --, you should set docIndex="", which int type connot set "" into its. So you should change the type of docIndex to other type that can set docIndex="".